# How to setup an Effect Audio Unit connected with RemoteIO Audio Unit in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I am new to Audio Units and don't know how to configure them. Can someone please guide me how to connect RemoteIO (kAudioUnitType_Output) unit with the effect unit (kAudioUnitType_Effect) to play audio file with effect. Thanks in advance.